# Python - How to handle image file sets whose name are sequential (list operation)

Tags: python, list, image, stack

I have 50 image data sets as image png files.
How can I stack to each condition data set to list, and put each list into function?
I'm a beginner of python, and I couldn't find such concrete data handling in my text book...

(****1st to 50th dataset-> sample1)
(1st data set of sample1 fabricated with condition1, each number of picture is 20)
sample1-condition1-no0001.png
sample1-condition1-no0002.png
...
sample1-condition1-no0020.png

(2nd data set of sample1 fabricated with condition2, 20 data)
sample1-condition2-no0001.png
sample1-condition2-no0002.png
...
sample1-condition2-no0020.png

... ...

(50th data set of sample1 fabricated with condition50, 20 data)
sample1-condition50-no0001.png
sample1-condition50-no0002.png
...
sample1-condition50-no0020.png

I want to stack each data set as

```
pictsample1 = np.stack([
imageio.imread("sample1-condition{i}-no{:04d}.png".format(n)) >50
for n in range(1, 20) 
for i in range(1,50)
```

], axis=0)

This didn't work. I think some grammar is wrong.

(Then I want to put in some function for each dataset, like below...)

```
answerlist{k}=function(pictsample1{k}, signed=True)
```

If anyone who knows well about list operation, could you please tell me??

(What I have done is following)

I tried to handle single data as follows

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
```

(handling only the first data of the first data set)

```
image_test = imageio.imread("experiment/sample1-condition1-no0001.png")
plt.imshow(image_test, "gray")
np.max(image_test)
np.min(image_test)
np.count_nonzero(img_diff)
```

(handling only the 20 data of the first data set)

```
pictsample1 = np.stack([
imageio.imread("sample1-condition{i}-no{:04d}.png".format(n)) >50
for n in range(1, 20)
```

], axis=0)
nonzerolist=np.nonzero(pict)
print(nonzerolist)

And now I want to do things like above for the each data set but I cannot stack data...
Please please tell me how to operate data set list.

Comment: Now I could make 2D string name list of the image files as,                                                      namelist=[['experiment/sample1-condition'+ format(i,'0')+'no_{:04d}.png'.format(n)
    for n in range(1, 21)
         ]
         for i in range(1,51)]But, unfortunately,                                                                                                     pictsample1 = np.stack([[
   imageio.imread(namelist[i][n]) >50
    for n in range(1, 21)
]
    for i in range(1, 51)
], axis=0)  
doesn't work. Error code was IndexError: list index out of range